# Printing Java array -- only last element's value is shown, why?

Tags: java, arrays

Just to keep my skills sharp, I decided to write a small programme that prints out the values of an array, after being given two variables that each contain a different value.

My expectation was that each value would show onscreen, but this did not happen. Instead, only the last element's value was displayed onscreen (in the code below, being the number "2" --> That is an integer, *not* a string).

Why is this?

Also, why does dynamic initialisation produce the result I wish, but not the way I do it in the code?

Many thanks.

```
int[] arrayOne;
arrayOne = new int[2];

int numOne = 1;`
int numTwo = 2;`

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {`

    arrayOne[i] = numOne;
    arrayOne[i] = numTwo;
    System.out.println(arrayOne[i]);

}
```

Comment: Note that you are setting each element to `numOne` then immediately overwriting with `numTwo`. This probably isn't want you want. Please explain what you want the array to have?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I wanted the array to have inside its two elements, the integers 1 and 2, not show the number two twice over. You have solved my quexstion, however. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the values of two variables into an array, you need to use two assignments:

```
arrayOne[0] = numOne;
arrayTwo[1] = numTwo;
```

Now you can use a for loop to print out the contents of the array.

This kind of defeats the purpose of using an array, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting different values to same location, causing only last value to be saved.

Your code similar to doing:

```
arrayOne[0] = 1;
arrayOne[0] = 2;
```

After these two lines, `arrayOne[0]` will hold the value of 2.

If you want to put these two values, you need to put them in different places:

```
arrayOne[0] = 1;
arrayOne[1] = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java (and in almost any language I know), an array can only contain one vale per cell i.e. if you do "array[i] = 1" and after "array[i] = 2" , then the i-cell will CHANGE its value from 1 to 2, not append the value 2 after the 1. In the end, youre array will contain numTwo in every single cell.

If you want to initialize the array with a different value in each cell, I'm afraid you need to do it manually, not using the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
public class demo{

    private static int i = 0;
    private static int[] demo = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            addElementToArray(i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < demo.length; i++){
            System.out.println(demo[i]);
        }
        addElementToArray(i);
    }

    public static void addElementToArray(int input){
        try{
            demo[i] = input;
            i++;
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't set the values inside the for-loop either, that is (imo) plain stupid, for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks Lars. What would I do then, if I wanted to add say, 10 user chosen numbers to an array? (I know how to get the input from the user and all that), but I am talking about then putting that input into a unique element automatically, without my having to manually define a value for it e.g. [0] = 5; [1] = 7; (and so on).

Comment: @PaulShalley this is really non pretty code, but take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the population of your array before you iterate through it with the loop.

```
arrayOne[0] = numOne;
arrayOne[1] = numTwo;
```

Then do your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.println(arrayOne[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to initialize an array...

```
int[] a = new int[2];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
```

Or:

```
int[] a = new int[2];
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){
  a[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Or:

```
int[] a = new int[]{ 1, 2 };
```

Or.

```
int valOne = 1;
int valTwo = 2;
int[] a = new int[]{ valOne, valTwo };
```

Take care when you see more than one assignment to the same array element in a loop as you have it before the println. Is this what you want? The second one wins and sets the current (i-th) element to 2.